# How to store simple piece of data online without using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, url, store

I'm creating an application for work in which I need to be able to disable the app if I leave the company. I'll maintain ownership and this agreement to cancel upon my departure is agreed upon in our contract.

Since these apps will be used by other people, I need to perform a "check" upon launching as to whether access is still granted or not.

I know that MySQL would be perfect for this by simply storing a 0 or 1 in a TINYINT table, but I don't want to use MySQL for this small task since I'd have to use free hosting which has proven hard in finding reliable hosts with remote access enabled.

Ideally I'd like a website that offers a personalized URL like http://randomURL.com/X38DAKNLD828ND that I could store a simple piece of text like "Enabled" or "Disabled".

There must be some simple way to store such a small piece of data?

Comment: isn't this sabotage?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. I'll own the applications they are using so when I leave the company I'll legally be permitted to cancel their usage. This is agreed upon within our contract. But since all of the apps will be on different PCs, I won't have direct access. That's why I need help. I'm confused why this is rated -2

Comment: Well from your original wording it sounded like sabotage. Please edit the question and add this info. That and the fact that this quesion is far too broad maybe why you have two down votes.

Comment: When you say: `all of the apps will be on different PCs` you mean user pcs? or server computers? The way you put that comment seems like you client/server applications. Are they web applications or client applications?

Comment: I mean user PCs; their personal computers. The apps I'm building are productivity tools that help increase efficiency of daily tasks by using automation. Once I leave, the apps leave with me. So I need to perform a "check" each time a user executes an app, to verify (online) that usage is still enabled. A simple yes/no needs to be saved somewhere STATIC that I can edit as I please, like MySQL.

Comment: you know how demo software expires after a month. How about something like that?

Comment: @ Strawberry.. Thank you, but I don't know when exactly I'll be cutting ties, so that's not really an option. I need something I can switch off at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try [parse.com](http://www.parse.com)

If you're writing a small/simple app (or a throwaway prototype) with little to no logic on the backend then go for it, but for something larger/scalable it's best to avoid it, I can say that from first hand experience

Comment: Thank you Subin. I'll check Parse out and report back!

Comment: Looks like the perfect solution! Thank you Subin.